# ggnet2 : Error: Each variable must be a 1d atomic vector or list

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to use ggnet2 for visualizing a network analysis, but have run into an error with the vignette.

I can generate a random network,

```
library(ggnet2)
library(network)
library(sna)
library(ggplot2)

net = rgraph(10, mode = "graph", tprob = 0.5)
net = network(net, directed = FALSE)

# vertex names
network.vertex.names(net) = letters[1:10]
```

With an output that looks reasonable

```
 >net
 Network attributes:
 vertices = 10 
directed = FALSE 
hyper = FALSE 
loops = FALSE 
multiple = FALSE 
bipartite = FALSE 
total edges= 28 
missing edges= 0 
non-missing edges= 28 

Vertex attribute names: 
vertex.names 

No edge attributes
```

However, when I try to run..

```
ggnet2(net)
```

I get an error

```
Error: Each variable must be a 1d atomic vector or list. Problem variables: 'x', 'y', 'xend', 'yend'
```

I am not clear on how this error is arising in the vignette as `net` is a list, and all variables within it are lists. I have checked to ensure that I have all the necessary packages and they are up-to-date as well as the most recent R version.

I just tried `ggnetwork` and seem to get a similar error.

Any thoughts on why this errors is arising?

Comment: I cant reproduce this (although i did include a `library(GGally)` call for the `ggnet2` function).

Comment: Ok thanks...must be something in my environment.

Comment: I had this same issue. I'm trying to follow the tutorial: https://briatte.github.io/ggnet/

Comment: Also experienced the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message says

```
Error: Each variable must be a 1d atomic vector or list. Problem 
variables: 'x', 'y', 'xend', 'yend'
```

If you do the following

```
library(ggnetwork)
net <- ggnetwork(net)
class(net$x)
```

you will find that `x` is a one column matrix.  The same is true for your other components.  So doing

```
net$x <- net$x[,1]
net$y <- net$y[,1]
net$xend <- net$xend[,1]
net$yend <- net$yend[,1]
```

will change these all to 1d atomic vectors and

```
ggplot(net, aes(x = x, y = y, xend = xend, yend = yend)) +
    geom_edges(aes(linetype = "directed"), color = "grey50")
```

should work.  You can read more about how to make ggnetwork work for prettier graphs.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue following the tutorial at [briatte.github.io/ggnet](http://briatte.github.io/ggnet).

The issue went away after I updated the 'igraph', 'ggplot', 'intergraph', 'GGally' packages and installed the 'ggnetwork' from source:
`install.packages("ggnetwork", type="source")`.

This was suggested [here](https://github.com/briatte/ggnetwork/issues/13) to fix another issue, but somehow it worked for me on this one. Perhaps you could give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've found a solution for the issue, at least on my machine. I'm running R 3.4.3 on Win 10, but this is probably not platform-related.

Until now I've had the CRAN version of `GGally` installed, along with `network` and `sna`, just as mentioned in the [example](https://briatte.github.io/ggnet/), and this setup threw the exact same error mentioned above. I was confused as the original `network` object doesn't even have members like `x`, `xend`, etc. It turned out that these are in fact members of the `ggnetwork` object, which is created invisibly during the command `ggnet()` ([ggnetwork vignette](https://briatte.github.io/ggnetwork/)).

So I've tried installing ggnetwork: `install.packages("ggnetwork")` along with the source version of ggnet
(`devtools::install_github("briatte/ggnet")`).

- ggnetwork was installed succesfully, but the package couldn't be loaded because it said that ggplot2 is not installed (which I've found strange because it's a package that I use on a daily basis as part of the `tidyverse` library).
- ggnet installation failed for some reason related to packages being already loaded.

I've restarted the R session, tried loading ggnetwork again, which again failed for lack of ggplot2, so I installed ggplot2. I tried once again installing ggnet from source, (this time before any packages were loaded) and it worked.

*So, to sum it up:*

After restarting the R session:

```
install.packages("ggnetwork")
install.packages("ggplot2")
devtools::install_github("briatte/ggnet")
```

I don't know exactly which step did it, but afterwards the example script produced a graph plot, just as it was supposed to:

```
library(ggnetwork)
library(network)
library(sna)
library(ggnet)

net = rgraph(10, mode = "graph", tprob = 0.5)
net = network(net, directed = FALSE)

network.vertex.names(net) = letters[1:10]

ggnet2(net)
```